# preg_match_all not finding all the patterns in a large text file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to build a [FaH](http://folding.stanford.edu/) stats scraper. Every hour the newly update stats list is pulled to my server via `cron` and `wget` into this file http://chrislabs.info/statsFile.txt. This is opened in the script as `$page` using `file_get_contents`.

Then, for a list of unique team numbers (the fourth column), I'm trying to regex all the rows containing that team number using the code below:

```
foreach($teamArr as $team){
    $pattern = "/(.*[ascii])\t([0-9]*)\t.*[0-9]\t$team/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $page, $matches);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
```

However, this isn't finding all the matches in `$page` and I'm at a loss now as to what to fix. I've changed the `pcre.*` INI settings to go up to 1GB.

You can look at the output here http://chrislabs.info/FoldingStats_MYSQL.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$pattern = '~^(?:\S++\t){3}' . $team . '$~m';
```

Your pattern didn't find all matches because you added `[ascii]` that only matches the letter a or the letter s or the letter c or the letter i. If you want to match all letters you must use `[a-z]`

An other way is to use [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and remove all records that are not from the team you are looking for.

You can also use two `explode()` the first with `\n` and the second with `\t` and check `$item[3]` for your team.

Comment: Thanks yes. I changed the pattern instead to

    $pattern = "/(.*[[:ascii:]])\t([0-9]*)\t.*[0-9]\t$team/";